# Codeigniter sessions, display user's firstname

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'm trying to display the user's firstname after login but it doesn't appear on the page. I tried to display it like this

```
<h2> Welcome <?php echo $this->session->userdata('firstname'); ?> </h2>
```

but it didn't display the user's firstname, even though there are data in DB. But when I tried to change the `'firstname'` into `'username'`, it displayed the email of the user(test@gmail.com). How can I display the user firstname? Here's my controller:

```
    function login(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
      redirect('/');

    } else {
      $user_login = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
      );
      $login = new UI_model;
      $result = $login->login_user($user_login);

      if($result){
        $auth_details = array(
          'firstname' => $result->firstname,
          'lastname' => $result->lastname,
          'username' => $result->username,
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($auth_details);
        // $this->session->set_userdata('authenticated', '1');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('status', 'User Logged in Successfully!');
        redirect(base_url('pages/index'));

      } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('status', 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again');
        redirect(base_url('pages/about'));
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's my Model:

```
public function login_user($data){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('username', $data['username']);
        $this->db->where('password', $data['password']);
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return $query->row();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach an image of your database you are using for and echo all data session?